# Codeception api suite,Ignore redirect

Tags: php, symfony, codeception

I have used codeception to test my api written in symfony framework, I have been stuck into a problem that one of my endpoint contains redirect.
How would I handle the redirect?
Below is my code snippet

```
 if ($request->get('error') == 'access_denied') {
        $error = array(
            'status' => $this->get(GenericConstants::TRANSLATOR)->trans('vk.page.error', array(), 'page'),
            'code' => 400,
            'channel' => 'VK',
            'user_identifier' => '',
            'profile_select' => 'true',
            'process' => $process_type,
            'message' => $this->get(GenericConstants::TRANSLATOR)->trans('vk.dashboard.error.userCancelled', array(), 'dashboard')
        );
        return **$this->redirect($setting_url . http_build_query($error));**
    }
```

Here is my test

```
 $customer = $this->ui->getCustomer();
    $user = $I->haveAVkUser();
    $application = $I->haveAVkApplication($customer);
    $owner = $I->haveAnOwner($customer, $this->ui);
    $community = $I->haveACommunity($customer, $owner, array('communityType' => 0));
    $I->sendGET(
        '/oauth/callback',
    [
        "state" => strtr(base64_encode($community->getId(). "-new") , '+/=', '-_,'),
        'code' => 404,
        'error' => "access_denied"


        ]
    );
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(\Codeception\Util\HttpCode::FOUND);
```

I want that I should not be redirected from test environment

Comment: Your question should include the code, desired behaviour and currenct behaviour.

Comment: I want that my testcase should not redirect but return some status code as soon as redirect code snippet come

Comment: Looks like you do not understand basics of Stackoverflow. Visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) than edit your question accordingly. Avoid commenting before you do both of these.

Comment: @svgrafov, As I am new to Stackoverflow So, please entertain my question as it is.Next time I will try to follow the formatting.

Comment: Either you edit your question so that it becomes answerable and it(maybe) gets answered, or it gets downvoted and closed, maybe removed. "English is not my native tongue", 'Next time I will follow the rules', 'Please debug my code without actual code' will not help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, you are using REST module here.

REST module has [stopFollowingRedirects](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/REST#stopFollowingRedirects) method.
Use it before `sendGET` call.

```
$I->stopFollowingRedirects();
$I->sendGET(
    '/oauth/callback',
    [
        "state" => strtr(base64_encode($community->getId(). "-new") , '+/=', '-_,'),
        'code' => 404,
        'error' => "access_denied"
    ]
);
```

If you need to re-enable redirects in the same test,
use `$I->startFollowingRedirects();`